Error with transformers interpret generration mixin
I am trying to use transformer interpret for a work project. I am using a midi conda virtual environment for python 3.12.4.
I get the following error (Full code below)
cannot import name 'GenerationMixin' from 'transformers.generation' (C:\some_path\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\transformers\generation_init_.py).
Did you mean: 'GenerationMode'?

Based on a similar question for sentence transformers (cannot import name 'GenerationMixin' from 'transformers.generation' while running executable file creating using pyinstaller)
I first  tried installing
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio

then I tried
pip install -U transformers-interpret

Finally
I opened the file C:\some_path\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\transformers_interpret_init_.py but wasn’t sure how to edit it.
I still get the same error mentioned above

Try importing via: from transformers.generation.utils import GenerationMixin

thanks that seemed to fix it code is now:
from transformers.generation.utils import GenerationMixin
from transformers_interpret import SequenceClassificationExplainer
